# adding a new column based upon values in another column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of a data frame `df$c_touch`:

```
c_touch
0
1
3
2
3
4
5
```

Where each number refers to a duration of time, such that `0 = 2 mins, 1 = 5 mins, 2 = 10 mins, 3=15 mins, 4=20 mins, 5=30 mins`.

I'd like to add another column `df$c_duration` to be like

```
c_touch c_duration
0 2
1 5
3 15
2 10
3 15
4 20
5 30
```

So far I've been using a loop, which is a bit ugly/messy, and I'd rather not use it. Is there a loop-free way of adding the extra column in, particularly using dplyr mutate function (as I'm trying to rewrite all my code using dplyr)?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the duration? Or is that the extent of c_touch. i.e. is there additional time durations after 5?

Comment: Yes. Just `merge` your data.frame and a lookup data.frame that maps c_touch to c_duration. You can do this using base R or dplyr or data.table or ...

Comment: Just create a named reference vector and match, e.g. `x <- setNames(c(2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30), 0:5) ; x[match(df$c_touch, names(x))]`. Also, I would recommend you to learn R before converting your code dplyr as your code contains loops because a luck of basic knowledge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    c_duration = case_when(
      c_touch == 0 ~ 2,
      c_touch == 5 ~ 30,
      TRUE ~ c_touch * 5
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
# data.frame containing the mapping
map <- data.frame(
    idx = 0:5,
    val = c(2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30))

# Sample data   
df <- read.table(text =
    "c_touch
0
1
3
2
3
4
5", header = T)

dplyr::left_join(df, map, by = c("c_touch" = "idx"))
#  c_touch val
#1       0   2
#2       1   5
#3       3  15
#4       2  10
#5       3  15
#6       4  20
#7       5  30
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dplyr::case_when inside mutate:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(c_duration = case_when(c_touch == 0 ~ 2,
        c_touch == 1 ~ 5,
        c_touch == 2 ~ 10,
        c_touch == 3 ~ 15,
        c_touch == 4 ~ 20,
        c_touch == 5 ~ 30))
```